# Deserializing JSON in a base type in C#/.NET4

Tags: c#, json

I am working on an JSON API client. The goal is to create a base type with the methods `ToJSON(..)` and `FromJSON(..)`, which subsequent classes can inherit from.

`ToJSON(..)` is relatively straight forward, following a blog article by Scott Guthrie (http://bit.ly/Ppgd3). I am struggling with the `FromJSON(..)`. Here is the basic code:

```
public class BaseType
{
    public virtual void FromJson(System.Type type, string input)
    {
        // What? How?
    }

    public virtual string ToJson()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serial = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serial.Serialize(this);
    }

    public virtual string ToJson(string verb)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serial = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string value = serial.Serialize(this);
        return string.Concat("{", "\"", verb.Trim(), "\":", value, "}");
    }
}
```

Now the way to do this is with `Deserialize(..)` and that works outside the class. My question is how to get the `Deserialize(..)` command below to work within the above class, under `FromJSON(..)`, in a way that is inheritable.

```
public class InheritedObject : BaseType { }

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serial = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
InheritedObject foo = serial.Deserialize<InheritedOjbect>(jsonString);
```

The language is C#, framework is .NET 4.0, and IDE is Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: The `from*` methods are typically `static`, since they create a *new* object from the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics would probably help in this case.

```
public virtual T FromJson<T>(string input)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serial = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serial.Deserialize<T>(input);
}
```

You would have to define T at the class level like so:

```
public class BaseType<T> where T : new()
```

Then inherit like so:

```
public class InheritedObject : BaseType<InheritedObject>
```

Or, make the method static:

```
public static T FromJson<T>(string input) where T : new()
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serial = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serial.Deserialize<T>(input);
}
```

Comment: Which object is the *virtual* `fromJson` called on? It only makes sense to make it static

Comment: I gave both options in case we don't have all the facts, but from what I can see in the limited code provided, static makes more sense.